# Is this vector constant?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $\vec{A} = a\hat{x} + b\hat{y} + c\hat{z}$ and $\vec{B} = a\hat{\rho} + b\hat{\phi} + c\hat{z}$ (cylindrical coordinates), where $a,b,c$ are constants, are $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ constant?

My argument is that if a vector $\vec{C}$ is constant, then $d\vec{C} = \vec{0},$ and so $\vec{A}$ is constant and $\vec{B}$ isn't, as neither $\hat{d\rho}$ nor $\hat{d\phi}$ equal $\vec{0}.$ Intuitively however, it seems like both $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are constant if you look at them as vector fields. Can someone help answer this problem?

Comment: Why do you think that $d\hat \rho$ is not $0$? Or $d\hat\phi$?

Comment: If $C$ is constant, what does $dC$ signify?

Comment: $d\hat{\rho} = d\phi \hat{\phi}$ by definition, so it isn't zero.

Comment: Are you talking about the magnitude of $\vec{C}$? Let me remind you that a vector also depends on direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see that $\vec B$ doesnt need to be constant, you just need to consider one choice of $a,b,c$ that gives a non-constant field.  For instance,

$$ \vec B := \hat \rho$$
is not constant.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up single vectors and vector fields. If you consider $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ as single vectors at a specific point in space then both are constant - they do not change with time or the price of fish or any other parameter. But if you consider them as vector fields i.e as a set of vectors associated with each point $P$ in $\mathbb R^3$ then $\vec B(P)$ is not constant because its direction is different at different points in space.

Note that $\vec A(P)$ is defined everywhere whereas $\vec B(P)$ is not defined at the origin because $\hat \rho$ and $\hat \phi$ are not defined there.